# Close navbar when clicked outside and not just the close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this working version of Navigation to open from the right side of the screen. It closes when I click on the close button.

I would like it to close when I click outside of the navbar too and just restrict it to the close button X. How should I proceed with that?

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: Are you by any chance opposed to using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

$('body').on('click', function(){
  if( parseInt( $('#mySidenav').css('width') ) > 0 ){
    closeNav();
  }
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: Any idea how to make this work in mobile touch screen too?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a click event listener to window, so if the user clicks anywhere the menu closes. If you don't want it to close if the user clicks an item in the menu, use

```
event.stopPropagation()

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";

    window.addEventListener(
        "click",
        closeNav
    );
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    window.removeEventListener("click", closeNav);
}
```

Comment: How do I do that? Could you help integrate with the current code?

Comment: I would consider seeking alternative methods. While it may 'work' there are certainly some intricacies to take into consideration. Please see the following for further detail: https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: It's not working. I'm getting 2 errors. One when I load the page `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined at a11.html:64` and when I click on it `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
    at closeNav (a11.html:77)`

Comment: I purposely posted the version without `event.stopPropagation`, look at what Chris Cruz said. If you want to use that, redefine `function closeNav ()` as `function closeNav (event)`, then you can use `event.stopPropagation()` inside said function. And sorry, it should've been `window.removeEventListener("click", closeNav)`, I believe.